# Update variables in a loop in one python script with input from another python script

Tags: python, loops

This is just an exercise to see how something like this would be done.

In file "variables.py" I have:

```
x=5
while True:
    x=input('input x: ')
```

In file "loop.py" I have:

```
import time
from variables import x
while True:
    print(str(x))
    time.sleep(2)
```

My goal is to have both programs running, where variables.py constantly asks for a new x value, and loop.py automatically updates the value of x in its loop. I set x=5 so that there's an initial value before I input anything.

Instead, when I run loop.py, I'm given an input prompt. How can I go about achieving something like this?

Comment: Uhh... your question makes it sound so easy, but thats actually a difficult concept. You'll want to look in to multprocessing and shared memory if you really want it to be between two processes using the same variable. The easiest way to accomplish something like this is to write to a database with one file and read from it with the other though, and avoid multiprocessing all together.

Comment: @Hoopdady Ah I see, I suppose I'm in a bit over my head then. I'll look into the methods you mentioned, thank you.

Comment: I didn't mean to scare you, the are many ways to accomplish the end goal, just the way you want to do it is difficult. If you are OK with writing to some sort of external object, like a database or a text file, then it gets really easy, but if you are wanting the two files to talk directly to each other, then it gets hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if `from variables import x` works while you run `variables.py`. So I would suggest to save x in a file what is used by both scripts (but not at the same time!):

```
x = 5
while True:
    x = input('input x: ')
    f = open('x.txt', 'w')
    f.write(x)
    f.close()
```

and

```
import time
while True:
    f = open('x.txt', 'r')
    print(f.read())
    f.close()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: This is also an easy alternative if you don't have really structured data and just need a way to share information between two process.